# pageIndex=1 will not count usernames in MembershipUserCollection

Tags: c#, collections, count, asp.net-membership

Ive been struggling with this test for most of the day. I had other issues that have been worked out in another post with this same code. My problem is with int pageIndex=1;

If pageIndex is set to "0" the test will fail but it will count usernames in the MembershipUserCollection. If the If pageIndex is set to any other number, the test will pass but will not allow it to count usernames in the collection.

What is the simplest way to resolve this so that my test will count the number of usernames it finds in the MembershipUserCollection? (the test should find 2 usernames, johnUser1 and johnUser2)

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestFindUsersByName()
    {
        try
        {

            //set test to create user 
            MembershipProvider prov = this.GetMembershipProvider();
            MembershipCreateStatus status;
            //creates users
            MembershipUser user1 = prov.CreateUser("johnUser1", "12345", "johnUser1@asc.edu", "", "", true, null, out status);
            MembershipUser user2 = prov.CreateUser("johnUser2", "12345", "johnUser2@asc.edu", "", "", true, null, out status);

            //gets users
            user1 = prov.GetUser("johnUser1", false); //not checking if user is online. Argument should be false. Not yet implemented 
            user2 = prov.GetUser("johnUser2", false);

            int pageSize = 1;
            int pageIndex=1;
            int totalRecords = 5;

            MembershipUserCollection coll = prov.FindUsersByName("john",pageIndex, pageSize, out totalRecords);


            List<string> UserName = new List<string>();

            foreach (MembershipUser user in coll)
            {

                UserName.Add(user.UserName);
            }
            Assert.AreEqual(2, coll.Count);
            Assert.IsNotNull(UserName);


            Assert.IsTrue(UserName.Contains("johnUser1"));


            //Deletes Users
            prov.DeleteUser("johnUser1", true);
            prov.DeleteUser("johnUser2", true);


            //Tries to get users again
            user1 = prov.GetUser("johnUser1", false);
            user2 = prov.GetUser("johnUser2", false);


            //test that no users are returned
            Assert.AreEqual(null, user1);
            Assert.AreEqual(null, user2);

            }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogMessage(ex);
            Assert.Fail(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: When pageIndex is 0, which Assert fails?  Is it `Assert.IsTrue(UserName.Contains("john"));`?  Since the usernames are johnUser1 and johnUser2, that code will fail, because contains in a list is different from contains in a string.

Comment: Assert.AreEqual(2, coll.Count) fails because the MembershipUserCollection doesnt count the usernames. I corrected the "johnUser1" I was aware of this and just forgot to change it before I moved the code to here.

Comment: From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.findusersbyname.aspx: "FindUsersByName returns a list of membership users where the user name matches the supplied usernameToMatch for the configured ApplicationName property. If your data source supports additional search capabilities, such as wildcard characters, you can provide more extensive search capabilities for user names."  From that, it doesn't look like you can match partial usernames using this function.

Comment: If you're looking for a count, maybe `GetAllUsers` would be better.  If you're using the live membership provider, I'd call it once before adding the two users and then call it again, and assert that it incremented by 2.

Comment: any suggestions on how to achieve a match partial usernames using some other function

Comment: Two points: 1) FindUsersByName is a method in the .NET framework.  I don't think a unit test testing the functionality of a non-custom method is necessary 2) if you really must test this method, add the users like you are doing, call GetAllUsers, then loop through or use LINQ to search for all user names that `.StartsWith("john")`.